# Scala: String Chomp

Tags: scala

does Scala have an API to do a "chomp" on a String?
Preferrably, I would like to convert a string "abcd   \n" to "abcd"

Thanks
Ajay

Comment: you should probably define what chomp does.  not every language has it as a standard string operation.

Answer (score 11):

There's `java.lang.String.trim()`, but that also removes leading whitespace. There's also `RichString.stripLineEnd`, but that only removes `\n` and `\r`.

Answer (score 4):

If you don't want to use Apache Commons Lang, you can roll your own, along these lines.

```
scala> def chomp(text: String) = text.reverse.dropWhile(" \n\r".contains(_)).reverse
chomp: (text: String)String

scala> "[" + chomp(" a b cd\r \n") + "]"
res28: java.lang.String = [ a b cd]
```

Comment: It gives me back ArrayBuffer. Not string

Answer (score 4):

There is in fact an out of the box support for *chomp*<sup>1</sup>

```
scala> val input = "abcd\n"
input: java.lang.String =
abcd


scala> "[%s]".format(input)
res2: String =
[abcd
]

scala> val chomped = input.stripLineEnd
chomped: String = abcd

scala> "[%s]".format(chomped)
res3: String = [abcd]
```

<sup>1</sup> *for some definition of chomp; really same answer as sepp2k but showing how to use it on `String`*

Answer (score 1):

Why not use [Apache Commons Lang](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) and the [StringUtils.chomp()](http://commons.apache.org/lang/api/org/apache/commons/lang/StringUtils.html#chomp%28java.lang.String%29) function ? One of the great things about Scala is that you can leverage off existing Java libraries.

Comment: That sucks. I would expect them to provide chomp support out of the box.

Comment: I am pretty sure "them" refers to Odersky/Typesafe.