# How to trim ending blanks of a string?

Tags: scala

In java, I can do it with `commons-lang`:

```
StringUtils.stripEnd("  abc  \t", null) // => "  abc"
```

I want to know if there is any built-in method to do this in scala, or how to do it in scala without any 3rd-party dependencies?

Comment: Since Java is completely interoperable with Scala, and Scala's strings are actually Java's strings you can use the same line of code you provided. Or are you asking about an idiomatic way of doing that in Scala?

Comment: @agilestell, you are right. Let me update the question

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2269509/scala-string-chomp Check *retronym* answer.

Comment: Yes, but I don't get a good answer in that question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can do it with a regex:

```
"  string  ".replaceAll("\\s+$", "");
res0: java.lang.String = "  string"
```

Comment: Wouldn't `replaceFirst` suffice here instead of `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 4):

Another possible way is to use method `dropWhile` from rich `String` class named `StringOps`

```
scala> val y = "   abcd   ".reverse.dropWhile(_ == ' ').reverse
y: String = "   abcd"
```

If you need to trim spaces from the beginning of string just remove `reverse` methods:

```
scala> val y = "   abcd   ".dropWhile(_ == ' ')
y: String = "abcd   "
```

Answer (score 2):

Without external dependencies and only end trimming:

```
scala> val s = "   test   \t"
s: java.lang.String = "   test      "

scala> val Regex = """^(.*?)\s*$""".r
Regex: scala.util.matching.Regex = ^(.*?)\s*$

scala> val Regex(trimmed) = s
trimmed: String = "   test"
```

Comment: Is it possible to write in one-line?